# Laravel Issue with Import CSS [with Homestead]

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-5, homestead

I'm using laravel 5 with Homestead.

When i try to import css,

```
rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}"
(DUE TO ENCODING ISSUE I SKIP : "<link>" TAG )
```

In browser i get output as,

```
  404 Not Found   http://wpshop.app/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

But the same CSS File is woking, when i use "http://localhost/".

What is wrong ?

How to import CSS in Homestead Application ?

Comment: Can you post important data from `Homestead.yaml` and `hosts` file in your home system please?

Comment: In according to my homestead is working fine. Issue is only on script pathing.